# In this select tag helper, why the .push?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So a tutorial I was following had this nice method of building a drop-down select menu for selecting years.

The instructor very deliberately used `.push` in the 6th line of code below.
Why? What could it be pushing? I've never seen this way of using it.

```
# payment.rb
def self.year_options
  (Date.today.year..(Date.today.year+10)).to_a
end

# new.html.erb
<%= p.select :card_expires_year, 
        options_for_select(Payment.year_options.push),                                                                  
        {include_blank:'Year'},
        'data-stripe'=>'exp-year',
        class:'form-control',
        required:true
%>
```

Comment: Good question. I wondered the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why `.push` is being used here. [The point of push is to add elements to an array.](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-push). Effectively that method is doing nothing here and you can call `Payment.year_options` without `.push`.

```
irb(main):003:0> options = (Date.today.year..(Date.today.year+10)).to_a
=> [2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2024, 2025]
irb(main):004:0> options.push
=> [2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2024, 2025]
```

Comment: thanks - thought there might be some unknown wizardry going on

Answer (score 1):

It does nothing. Try it out in your rails console:

```
pry(main)> [1,2,3].push
=> [1, 2, 3]
```

Just delete it.

In case you're not aware, the purpose of push is to add an element to an array - so we could do this:

```
[1,2,3].push(4)
=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

and it'd add 4 to our array. Push with no parameter? No point.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason for doing that. [Array#push](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-push) is used to append an element to an array. In this case where no argument is given there is no impact to the initial array.

A possible use case (which does not apply here) is if `Payment.year_options` was an `ActiveRecord::Relation` where `.push` would evaluate it to an array (but it would still be a weird way to do it).

Comment: ah -- that explains why the instructor may have picked up that habit, even though it isn't an ActiveRecord object in this case - thanks!